# Why are there so many already answered 3-10year old posts in the active feed?

Tags: discussion, support, bug

Why are there so many 3-10year old posts that are already answered like some years ago in the active feed?

For example I saw posts like [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/6290/how-is-it-possible-that-people-observing-an-https-connection-being-established-w) recently

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 2 main reasons:

1. questions that have no votes on the answers are bumped to the main page for activity
2. recent edits act as "recent activity" that brings the posts to the main page

For your example, one of the answers was edited:

> edited Jun 3 at 9:04

Comment: Yeah but why is the algorithm pushing those posts again? Most of the edits are just fixing typos

Comment: I don't understand your question. If you look at the post you linked, it shows that someone made the edits. Not an algorithm.

Comment: I mean a random user only edited and fixed a typo and thats already enough for the post to land on the main page again

Comment: Yes, as I mentioned in my answer. It's the same across StackExchange. I'm not sure what the problem is.

Comment: @UndercoverDog: By default, the main page sorts by "Active" rather than "Hot." You can change this by clicking the buttons in the top right (just under "Ask Question").